# In Django admin how can i hide or remove the Pencil, "+" and "x"?

Tags: django, django-admin, admin

I can hide all the options in the model base, but is not necessary, on the relation i can't do that i think that exist a simple form (not with css) to remove or hide it

[image: These are]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with [Ivan Camilito Ramirez Verdes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5393621/ivan-camilito-ramirez-verdes)'s solution :

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = (
        'my_field',
    )

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['my_field'].widget.can_change_related = False
        form.base_fields['my_field'].widget.can_add_related = False
        return form
```

Answer (score -1):

I presume you wish to disable the `ADD`, `EDIT`, and `DELETE` functionalities from the admin.

The [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_add_permission) provides the following functions that you can override in your `ModelAdmin`:

```
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_change_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request):
        return False
```

Comment: Thanks, finally I use it:

        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
            form.base_fields['form_field_name'].widget.can_add_related = False
            form.base_fields['form_field_name'].widget.can_delete_related = False

        return form